# Using Scrapy to extract data: following-sibling maybe?

Tags: html, scrapy

I am a noob using Scrapy to get various data, and need some help. I have looked around the forums but haven't been able to work out how to solve my issue from the examples. Here is the HTML

```
<section>
<div class="profile-details" >
    <div >
        <h5 style="margin-bottom:0px;">Contact Details</h5><div class="profile-phone">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th class='phone-number'>XX XXX XXXX</th>
                    </tr>
```

In the case of phone numbers, I have this

`item['phone'] = content.select('//*[@id="listing"]/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th[2]').extract()`

which returns `<th class="phone-number">XX XXX XXXX</th>` into the 'phone' field

However, I only am wanting to return 'XX XXX XXXX'. Is `following-sibling` the correct method, and/or how would I alter my code to retrieve just the 'XX XXX XXXX'?

Thanks, and don't fear the noob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `html` is invalid. Regardless of that you need the `text()` function:

```
item['phone'] = content.select('//*[@id="listing"]/section/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th[2][@class="phone-number"]/text()').extract()
```